# Django Streaming

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I just started with django and I want to make a spotify clone. I want to make it so then when you click on an album it shows the songs for that album.

this is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

    class album(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        artist = models.IntegerField()
        genre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        artwork = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    
    
    class artist(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    
    class song(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        artist = models.IntegerField()
        album = models.IntegerField()
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import album, song

def home(request):
    context = {
        'albums': album.objects.all(),

       
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

For that particular `album` for which the button is clicked, or all `albums`, please clarify your question.

Well, it cane achieved through frontend using `dropdowns` and much more components, or simply redirecting to another page which will show relevant albums.

Through `django`, if you need to see all albums so you are doing correct.

But if you see a particular `album` by clicking, so you have to pass that `album's id` or `name` or you can pass anything which is unique.

urls.py

```
path('particular-album/<int:id>/,views.particular_album,name='particular')
```

Html file

```
{% for album in albums %}
<a href="{% url 'particular' album.id %}">see particular album</a>
```

Views.py

```
def particular_album(req,id):
    one_album=album.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(req,"main/particular.html",{'one':one_album})
```

Then in your `template` file without running the loop you can get all the properties of this object.

If there are more than one objects, so you can use `album.objects.filter(field_name=variable)` same as like one object, but it gives you more than one, and the `variable` you have to pass must not be associated with `unique` constraint.So, it gives you all objects which belong to particular `category`.Then, you have to run loop in your `template` file.